# Code gives me Compile Error, Expected: List Separator or )

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel VBA button code which will copy a data in columns `A8:A399`, `B8:B399`, `C8:C399`, `D8:D399`, `E8:E399`, `F8:F399`, `G8:G399`, `H8:H399` one of the excel workbook to another workbook without opening it. But the Code I am using gives me an error message saying:

> Compile Error, Expected: List Separator or )

and it highlights the `(:)` in `Set myData = Workbooks.SaveAs(“C:\Users\athif\Desktop\Test_Pos\DataBase.xlsx”)`. Please tell me a solution.

Here is my Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    LR = Range("A399").End(xlUp).Row
    LR1 = Range("B399").End(xlUp).Row
    LR2 = Range("C399").End(xlUp).Row
    LR3 = Range("D399").End(xlUp).Row
    LR4 = Range("E399").End(xlUp).Row
    LR5 = Range("F399").End(xlUp).Row
    LR6 = Range("G399").End(xlUp).Row
    LR7 = Range("H399").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim itemIndex As String
    Dim itemNumber As String
    Dim itemDetails As String
    Dim itemPrice As Single
    Dim itemCust_nam As String
    Dim itemMobile As String
    Dim itemDate As String
    Dim itemTime As String
    Dim myData As Workbook

Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Select
    itemIndex = Range("A8:A" & LR)
    itemNumber = Range("B8:B" & LR1)
    itemDetails = Range("C8:C" & LR2)
    itemPrice = Range("D8:D" & LR3)
    itemCust_nam = Range("E8:E" & LR4)
    itemMobile = Range("F8:F" & LR5)
    itemDate = Range("G8:G" & LR6)
    itemTime = Range("H8:H" & LR7)


Set myData = Workbooks.SaveAs(“C:\Users\athif\Desktop\Test_Pos\DataBase.xlsx”)

Worksheets(“Sales”).Select
Worksheets(“Sales”).Range(“A1”).Select
RowCount = Worksheets(“Sales”).Range(“A1”).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets(“Sales”).Range(“A1”)
    .Offset(RowCount, 0) = itemIndex
    .Offset(RowCount, 1) = itemNumber
    .Offset(RowCount, 2) = itemDetails
    .Offset(RowCount, 3) = itemPrice
    .Offset(RowCount, 4) = itemCust_nam
    .Offset(RowCount, 5) = itemMobile
    .Offset(RowCount, 6) = ItemData
    .Offset(RowCount, 7) = itemTime
End With

myData.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: There is no `Workbooks.SaveAs` method. I suspect you mean `Workbooks.Open`. You also need to replace those curly quotes with regular quotes.

Answer (score 8):

There are lot of errors with that line

1. You are using `“`. You need to use `"`
2. `Workbooks` do not have the `.SaveAs` property

If you are trying to save the current workbook then do this

```
Dim myData As Workbook

Set myData = ThisWorkbook
myData.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\athif\Desktop\Test_Pos\DataBase.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

For file formats, you may want to see [THIS](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm) Link.